# OpenGL: Can not render VAO when stored in a different class

Tags: java, c++, opengl, visual-c++

Here is the problem. I am starting to move from OpenGL - Java engine, to OpenGL - C++ engine. The problem is when trying to store VAOs in classes. It seems to not render the test triangle in some cases. If I use `renderMesh(Mesh &mesh)` instead of `renderMesh(Mesh &mesh)` in most cases it works.

Loader class code:

```
void Loader::bindBuffer(GLuint vboID, GLfloat* data)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

Mesh Loader::getMeshData(GLfloat * verts, unsigned int numVerts)
{
    GLuint vaoID = createVAO();
    GLuint vboID = createVBO();
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    bindBuffer(vboID, verts);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    unBindVAO();
    return Mesh(vaoID, numVerts);
}
```

Renderer class code:

```
void MasterRenderer::renderMesh(Mesh mesh)
{
glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVAOID());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.getVerticiesAmount());
glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Mesh class code:

```
Mesh::Mesh(GLuint vaoID, unsigned int vertex_amount)
{
    this->vaoID = vaoID;
    this->vertex_amount = vertex_amount;
}

GLuint Mesh::getVAOID()
{
    return this->vaoID;
}

int Mesh::getVerticiesAmount()
{
    return this->vertex_amount;
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
}
```

The loader class seems to not load anything when used. Should I use VAO pointers in the mesh class? Should I return new Mesh from getMeshData? What could I do?
Any relevant help will be much appreciated!

EDIT:

Just found an answer to my problem. When passing the array of GLfloats to `getMeshData` it becomes a pointer. I then get the sizeof the pointer and NOT the array passed in.

FIX: `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data)* _num_elements, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`